# One of the object is behind a nother, but it's still visible

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a problem with final compositing. I did make a planet with a ring, but behind the planet, the ring is still visible. I have an atmosphere too, but I think that's not a problem. Can anybody help?
Here is what I like to see and what I see:
[image: You can see the ring is still visible where it's behind the planet.]

And this is my composition:
[image: My composition]